# How can I visualize 4d spatial data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with xyz coordinates and time. I'd like to be able to visualize it so that I have a sort of itinery map. I'd also like to compute the physical distance travelled between data points.

I'm relatively new in R. I searched up a few packages but they don't seem like they can achieve this. Can someone point me to the right direction, please?

Comment: General questions about data visualization are a better fit for [stats.se]. That's not really on-topic for Stack Overflow. Here you should provide some sample data and clearly describe the desired output. But if you don't know what you want the output to look like exactly, it's hard to help. There's no one solution that works best for all data of all dimensions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "itinery map" ?

Comment: This is one approach:  https://dmurdoch.github.io/rgl/reference/ageControl.html .